# Lazy loading a module from compiled library in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lazy-loading, jit

I am trying to lazy load NgModule from a library. I have a ng app, which contains some libraries (projects). This libraries are reused in some other projects. The problem is i can't find a solution, that would work with both jit and aot, and compiled/not compiled library.

file structure is like this

```
app
-projects
--lib
---(lib files)
-src
--(app files)
```

AppModule has routing, which looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'eager',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LibComponent // component imported from lib
            },
            {
                path: 'lazy',
                loadChildren: 'lib/src/lib/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' // module i want to load lazily
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

if i use it like this, i get runtime error when trying to navigate to lazy route in jit (aot works correctly):
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function`

this comment https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9488#issuecomment-370065452 suggests not to include LazyModule to any barrel files, but if i exclude it from public_api of library i get build error:

```
ERROR in ./projects/lib/src/lib/lazy/lazy.module.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\projects\lazy_minimal\lazy-minimal\projects\lib\src\lib\lazy\lazy.module.ts is missing from the TypeSc
ript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\projects\lazy_minimal\lazy-minimal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpac
k\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:752:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\projects\lazy_minimal\lazy-minimal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31
)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

is there any way to make it work for both aot and jit?

Comment: it is still impossible without wrapper module: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373#issuecomment-453006158

Comment: Did you try not to use barrel files at all ? I have had weird behaviour occur when using barrel files and lazy loaded modules in the past.

Comment: trick with wrapper seems to lazy load only wrapper module, when module from library i need to be lazy is included in main bundle

Comment: barrel file is public api in root of the library, it is specified as entry point for ng-package.json. how can i build library avoiding it?

Comment: check the updated post @ADAmelin

Answer (score 8):

There is an [issue in Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373) about loading compiled library in node_modules in lazy loading way. The following is [the workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373#issuecomment-453006158) suggested by [Alan Agius](https://github.com/alan-agius4)

> This thread was opened a while ago. Having so comments makes it hard
> for people to find information in anything but the latest comments.
> But on the other hand I don't think most people would go through all
> of the comments anyway. New users that see this thread mostly read the
> first and latest comments and lose things said in between.
>
> So for the reasons stated above (high volume of comments, hidden
> comments, hard to report and inform people) I'm locking this issue to
> prevent this comment from being lost as new comments come in.
>
> Thank you to everyone that reported and helped diagnose the problems
> and provided workarounds.
>
> Our recommended approach to lazy load a library within an angular
> workspace or node modules, is to use a proxy/wrapper module. With this
> approach lazy loading will works in both JIT and AOT mode. There are
> other solutions that work solely in AOT mode such as tsconfig imports
> however for a better development experience we don't encourage this.
>
> Below find an example of the recommended approach;
>
> `lazy/lazy.module.ts`
>
> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
> import { LibModule, LazyComponent } from 'my-lib';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     LibModule,
>     RouterModule.forChild([
>       { path: '', component: LazyComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
>     ])
>   ]
> })
> export class LazyModule { }
> ```
>
> `app.module.ts`
>
> ```
> import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
> import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
>
> import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
> import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     HomeComponent,
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     RouterModule.forRoot([
>       { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
>       { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'},
>     ]),
>   ],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

Comment: Now receive `Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!` when doing this in Angular9, FYI

Comment: Lazy loading in angular 9 is a lot different with angular 7 https://johnpapa.net/angular-9-lazy-loading-components/

Comment: Turned out it's an issue with ivy and symlinks. A temporary fileset gets created but not in time for the server to pick it up and outside the filewatch. Seems to work when stopping the server and running again.